# Magento Category URL slugs being appended to Wordpress blog posts?

Tags: magento-1.8, url, wordpress

Got a very strange problem here. We have Magento Community 1.8.1 and use Wordpress as our blog. Recently we have spotted an large increase in the number of 404 errors listed in Google Webmaster Tools/Search Console for our blog.

When I review the urls they look like this:

- /blog-post-name/magento-category/magento-subcategory.html
- /blog-post-name/magento-category.html
- /blog-tag/tag/magento-category/magento-subcategory.html
- /blog-author/authorname/magento-category/magento-subcategory.html

I have no idea if this is Magento automatically appending these slugs to the Wordpress urls or the other way around.

Any ideas are Welcome and I appologise if this should be posted in a Wordpress StackExchange?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make your question more clear by explaining where in Magento those URLs are posted? Are they in CMS pages you have coded? If yes how are you putting your URLs in your CMS pages coding? Are you using double curly bracket notation such as `<a href="{{store url="accessoires/blah"}}">blah</a>`?

Comment: These urls are not part of Magento. We are using Wordpress and it is installed on a subdirectory of our Magento website. www.mysite.com/blog/ + URLs listed above.